# ADT Can't install on Android device in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

this morning I have a very strange problem with ADT.
When I try to install on device in debug mode, on the device appears the "Waiting for debugger" dialog but then nothing happens.

But if I only Run the app ADT install it on device without problem.

**Edit - Here what LogCat says**

Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing it.app.webservice.login.activity.LoginActivity activity launch
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
Starting activity it.app.webservice.login.activity.LoginActivity on device 4109eb8833ed3883
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=it.app.webservice/.login.activity.LoginActivity }

**Edit - Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1**

Ideas ?

Comment: What does LogCat say?

Comment: which device you are using..?

Comment: have you enable USB debugging?

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: I'm using Android 4.1.2

Comment: is android:debuggable=true in the AndroidManifest?